# Text is turnicated in react-native like in below image

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

[The image that shows the turnicated off text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvamx.jpg)

Here, In the above image the text h is hidden or being turnicated off as I want to display text as english. Same error is on United states case as only United is only being displayed. Here is my code :-

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={onPress}>
      <Image source={imageSource} style={styles.image} />
      <Text textBreakStrategy="simple" style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      <Text textBreakStrategy="simple" style={styles.subtitle}>{subtitle}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

And css / stylesheet is :-

```
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignContent: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    textAlign: "center",
    width: 180,
    height: 136,
    Color: "#FFFFFF",
    border: "1px solid #00853E",
    borderColor: "#00853E",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 1,
    boxShadow: "0px 4px 10px rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.25)",
    borderRadius: 3,
  },
  image: {
    width: 76.92,
    height: 54.94,
    resizeMode: "contain",
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: 7,
    fontStyle: "normal",
    fontWeight: 400,
    fontSize: 18,
    lineHeight: 23,
    color: "#00853E",
  },
  subtitle: {
    fontStyle: "normal",
    fontWeight: 400,
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 23,
    color: "#3F3F3F",
  },
```

I have tried using textBreakStrategy="simple" but it doesn't work also tried using flex wrap , overflow : 'scroll' , alignSelf: 'stretch', textAlign: 'center',

Answer (score 0):

have you tried giving a fixed width to the text

```
 title: {
marginTop: 7,
fontStyle: "normal",
fontWeight: 400,
fontSize: 18,
lineHeight: 23,
color: "#00853E",
width:180
```

},

Comment: Ok got it , I will try this , But why is it working on some device and turnicated off in some devices I just want to know that.